# Angular - How to inject pipes into directive

Tags: angular

I have set a directive which gives format to an input value depending on de pipe you pass as a parameter (@Input). I use it for reactive forms.

To do this I have needed to import all the desired pipes (one for now), and provide a switch to get the right one to use.

My question is: Is there a way to get any pipe from an injector just knowing its token, as `const pipe = injector.get(‘currency’)`;

This is my directive code:

```
import { Input, Renderer2, ElementRef, forwardRef, Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
    selector: '[formatInput]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, multi: true, useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormatInputDirective) },
    ],
})
export class FormatInputDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
    private changeCallback: Function;
    private touchedCallback: Function;

    @Input() pipe: any; // { token: string, args: any[] }

    @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
    onChange(value) {
        this.changeCallback(value);
    }

    @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target'])
    onBlur(target) {
        this.touchedCallback();
    }

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private currency: CurrencyPipe, private elRef: ElementRef ) {
        this.changeCallback = (_: any) => {};
        this.touchedCallback = () => {};
    }

    writeValue(value: any): void {
        this.renderer.setProperty(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'value', this.setPipedValue(value));
    }

    setPipedValue(value: any): any {
        if (!this.pipe || !value) {
            return value;
        } else {
            let pipe;

            switch (this.pipe.token) {
                case 'currency':
                    pipe = this.currency;
                    break;
            }
            return pipe.transform(value, ...this.pipe.args);
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn) {
        this.changeCallback = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.touchedCallback = fn;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual with injection, you first have to *provide* the thing you want to use.
In the corresponding `NgModule`, add `CurrencyPipe` (and all others you want to inject later) to the array of `providers`.

```
providers: [CurrencyPipe],
```

Now inject the `Injector`, by adding it to the constructor of your directive.

```
constructor (private injector: Injector)
```

Use it to grab an instance of a pipe you want by using the `get` method and the token as an argument. In this case, the token is the class itself.

```
const pipe = injector.get(CurrencyPipe)
```

Now you have an instance of pipe.
You can use its `transform` method to perform the transformation.

```
this.value = pipe.transform(123456789)
```

You can [see this in action on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jojpjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Note that Angular doesn't have a concept of dependency injection using strings. You can use tokens instead, but that doesn't give you much power over what you already have with classes in case of pipes.

If you want to specify the pipe as a string, you have to define the mapping yourself.

```
const MAP = { 'currency': CurrencyPipe, 'decimal': DecimalPipe }
```

Now use this mapping to spawn an instance of the correct pipe.

```
const pipeName = 'currency'
const pipeClass = MAP[pipeName]
const pipe = injector.get(pipeClass)
const value = pipe.transform(input)
```

Comment: I had tried the to get the pipe from the injector using a string. Your explanation made it much clearer. I have used your Map proposition and works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: What I have finally done, and due to I have to provide the pipe classes anyhow, is to use a string token in my provide declaration (`{ provide: 'currency', useClass: CurrencyPipe }`) and that way I can get the pipe from the injector just with the string.  What it’s true is that I have to do all the imports in the appModule, but not twice at least. Maybe my initial purpose didn’t make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

In angular 6 filter methods are also exported from `@angular/common` package directly, e.g.:

```
import { formatCurrency } from '@angular/common';
```

https://angular.io/api/common/formatCurrency

Or you can simply instantiate the pipe yourself, without using DI as it is simple helper class without any dependencies:

```
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

const pipe = new CurrencyPipe('en-US');
pipe.transform(...);
```

Comment: The locale is a dependency. You're using `en-US` here.

Comment: Well `en-US` is the default value. Not a real dependency, just scalar value, nothing you need DI for.

Comment: If you change the locale, you do.

Comment: Actually, I’m using another locale. But my main concern was trying to avoid importing, or instantiating, every pipe I needed. Lazar Ljubenovic gave I nice explanation of why my approach with strings was wrong. The final solution is not perfect, because I still have to import the different pipes, but changes the code a little bit and is good enough for me. Ideally get rid of all pipe imports and just use the injector.